# how to copy table between two database using php+mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

how to copy table between two database using php+mysql?

sometimes I want to use php copy table derectly between two tables, it seems too hard for me. is there anyone know how to do it ?pls see my code bellow:

```
<?php 

// database: a   ,  table: user
name | age | sex
jimmy | 30 | male
ricky | 20 | male
tina | 20 | female

// database: b   ,  table: user
name | age
kelvin | 30

// I want to copy a.user to replace b.user completely, how to do it in php+mysql?
$db_a = $db->connect($a_config);
$db_b = $db->connect($b_config);
// $db_a->table('user')->copy_to($db_b); // only explaining what I want to do

// final result: b.user is
name | age | sex
jimmy | 30 | male
ricky | 20 | male
tina | 20 | female
```

Comment: PHP + MySQL = PHPMYADMIN.  Give it a try, it does this well by standardizing exporting and importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table db_a.table_name like db_b.table_name;
```

After creating table you have to insert data like this

```
insert into db_b.table_name select * from db_a.table_name;
```

Comment: the two db are using two connect config, can not do it in one sql

Comment: do you want in mysql or sql?

Comment: mysql, "one sql" = "insert into db_b.table_name select * from db_a.table_name;"

Comment: What happen using this query it is work or not?

Comment: $db_a is linking a database, it is not for b. $db_a don't know db_b in "insert into db_b.table_name select * from db_a.table_name;"

Comment: thank you very much ,seems no ways to do that in php

Comment: Please don't spread false rumors, if you still don't know how to do this in PHP it doesn't mean it cant be done in php. There are one million twelve hundred fifty seven ways to do this in php.